# Use of same related_name in a single Model. Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a User model:

```
Class User(models.Model):
   #some fields
```

And another Profile Model, which consists of fields -> mother and father.

```
Class Profile(models.Model):
   father = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    related_name='children',
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   mother = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    related_name='children',
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Now, is it right to do so? If it is, How am I to get a User's children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a property?

```
class User(models.Model):
   #some fields

   @property
   def children(self):
      if self.gender == 'm':
         return self.father_children.all()
      return self.mother_children.all()
```

And

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   father = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    related_name='father_children',
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   mother = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    related_name='mother_children',
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Not ideal, but it's something

Comment: I have  a problem. The gender is in Profile models itself and not user.

Answer (score 2):

change model to below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
   # ....
   gender = models.ChoiceField(choices=(('m', 'Male'), ('f', 'Female')))
   # .... 

   def children(self):
       if self.gender == 'm':
          return self.fchildren
       return self.mchildren

class Profile(models.Model):
   father = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    related_name='fchildren',
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   mother = models.ForeignKey(
    'User',
    related_name='mchildren',
    on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

Access the urls

```
 user = User.objecets.get(pk=10)
 children = user.children.all()
```

Comment: But it creates an extra burden to check whether the User is a father or mother, by checking their gender or so.

Comment: Instead I require an abstraction so that I need not check for gender and using `user.children.all()`  must query all the children.

Comment: I have a problem. The gender is in Profile models itself and not User.